# k8s dynamically set number of replicas relative to number of nodes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Is there a feature or param to put in my deployment yaml (`kind: Deployment`) to tell k8s to deploy as many replicas as there are nodes in the cluster?

Answer (score 4):

[Daemonset will fulfill your requirements](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/)

Comment: hmm i dont know if I want one pod per node in all cases and might want to do horizontal pod scaling at some point.

Comment: Usually the concepts of "I want a pod running on every node" and "I want my deployment to scale as needed" are mutually exclusive.  You'd usually want something on each node doing some sort of node maintenance (cache or storage mangement, log collection and distribution etc).  If it's something that should autoscale based on usage, it shouldn't really care about what node it's running on.  (That said, I'd love to hear a use case where a Daemonset should be scalable . It's probably a really interesting problem)

Answer (score 0):

you can maybe use custom definitions for the autoscaler.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/